# Link a SharePoint list item with a document library based on list field holding the URL of the library

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I am able to link to a library after a SharePoint list item is created.
I have a field called "Link" and I have JSON that helps with the link but I have to hard code the URL in the JSON for it to work.
I would rather use a field in my list called "SiteURL", which holds the URL of the site where the library resides but then open the library as well.
Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build a URL dynamically using an expression. I don't have your full format, but a simple link format below will show what I mean by an expression:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=[$SiteURL] + '/libraryname/allitems.aspx'",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "style": {
    "display": "=if([$SecurityType] == 'Secure Folder', 'inherit', 'none')"
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks.
Is it possible to not have any text in the link column based on another fields input?
I have a choice field named "SecurityType" that shows either Secure Folder or Secure Site. I would only want the link field show the link if "Secure Folder" is selected.

Comment: @ChristopherLond yes. I've edited the answer to add an expression to the `display` property. This will hide the entire element if the `SecurityType` column is not `Secure Folder`